# Proving that, under certain conditions, $A_n p^n$ approaches 0 along some subsequence $\{n_k\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $(A_n)$ be a non-decreasing sequence of natural numbers and $p$ be a probability; i.e., $p \in [0,1]$. If $p < \frac{1}{\liminf_{n}(A_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$, then $A_n p^n$ approaches 0 along some subsequence $\{n_k\}$.

Here is my **attempt** to prove it (*spoiler*: it didn't work):

$A_n p^n = \left(p\sqrt[n]{A_n}\right)^n < \left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{A_n}}{\liminf_{n}\sqrt[n]{A_n}}\right)^n$. Now, notice that there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $\lim_{n_k}\sqrt[n_k]{A_{n_k}} = \liminf_{n}\sqrt[n]{A_n}$; therefore, $(p \sqrt[n_k]{A_{n_k}})^{n_k} < \left(\frac{\sqrt[n_k]{A_{n_k}}}{\liminf_{n}\sqrt[n]{A_n}}\right)^{n_k}$. Here, if $\sqrt[n_k]{A_{n_k}} < \liminf_{n}\sqrt[n]{A_{n}}$, for a large $n_k$, I got the desired convergence.

As $(A_{n_k})$ is a non-decreasing sequence; i.e, $A_{n_{k+1}} \geq A_{n_k}$, $\forall n_k$, it follows that $\sqrt[n_{k+1}]{A_{n_{k+1}}} \geq \sqrt[n_k]{A_{n_k}}$ (which is **NOT** necessarily true, *here is my mistake*). Then, since $\sqrt[n_k]{A_{n_k}}$ approximates $\liminf_{n}\sqrt[n]{A_{n}}$ from below, for an arbitrarily large $n_k$, the desired convergence is achieved.

Actually, it would be achieved if I'd not made such a mistake (which I do not know how to repair $-$ that is the reason of my post).

Does anyone have a better idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $q$ such that $p<q<1/(\liminf A_n^{1/n}).$ Then

$$\frac{1}{p} > \frac{1}{q} > \liminf A_n^{1/n}.$$

This implies

$$\frac{1}{p} > \frac{1}{q} > A_{n_k}^{1/n_k}$$

along a subsequence $n_k.$ Now raise to the $n_k$ power and multiply through by $p^{n_k}$ to get

$$\left (\frac{p}{q}\right)^{n_k} > p^{n_k} A_{n_k}.$$

Since $p/q<1,$ we have the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a not very smart question, but after "_This implies, $[\cdots]$_", instead of ${A_{n_k}}^{\frac{1}{n_k}}$, shouldn't you use $\lim_{n_k}{A_{n_k}}^{\frac{1}{n_k}}$ "_$[\cdots]$ along a subsequence $n_k$_"? It is not the same, is it?

Comment: I don't think we need to put $\lim$ there; it's fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell = \liminf_nA_n^{1/n}$. Then your condition means $\ell < \frac 1p$. So, $\frac 1p = \gamma\ell$ for some $\gamma > 1$. The fact that $\ell$ is the $\liminf$ implies that for each $1<\beta < \gamma$ we have that $A_n^{1/n} < \beta\ell$ for almost all $n$, i.e., $A_n < \beta^n\ell^n$. Hence,
$$
A_np^n = A_n\cdot\frac 1{\gamma^n\ell^n} < \frac{\beta^n\ell^n}{\beta^n\ell^n} = \left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\right)^n
$$
for $n\ge N$. And since $\beta/\gamma < 1$, this tends to zero. So, you don't only have a subsequence, but a whole tail of the sequence tends to zero.